# a better way to create a map from a list

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a function that look like:

```
 def functionTrans(f: FunctionDec) = {

    // some FunctionDec manipulation

    f.name -> FuncEntry(/* something here*/)
  }
```

Witch basically do a manipulation of FunctionDec and turn into a Pair (String, FuncEntry). 
Also i have a **Map[String, FuncEntry]** called **varsEnv** and a **List[FunctionDec]** called **decs**. I need apply that manipulation to all the list and return an augmented Map.
What i did looks like:

```
val venvWithFunction = decs.foldLeft(varsEnv)(_ + functionTrans(_))
```

There's a better scala-colection way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decs.map(functionTrans _).toMap` should suffice.

Comment: something like:
val venvWithFunction = varsEnv ++ decs.map(functionTrans) ?

Comment: @Joselo if `varsEnv` is not empty, then this: `varsEnv ++ decs.map(functionTrans).toMap`. You need `toMap` to transform a `List[(A, B)]` into a `Map[A, B]`.

Comment: @Ionut, without **.toMap** works too, do you know why?

Comment: @Joselo interesting. I didn't know until now, but it looks like there's a `++` overload which takes a collection of tuples, just like in your case.